# Second Play Issue

Tags: soundmanager2

My problem is once the audio track stops playing and you go to hit the play button for a second time, the song just doesn't play. By this i mean i don't hear anything playing but the first time works fine.

```
 soundManager.url = '{{ asset('bundles/bm/swf/')}}';
    soundManager.onload = (function() {
        var preview = soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'previewer',
            url: '{{ path('play_track', { 'id' : track.id}) }}',
            type: 'audio/mp3'
        });
        preview.options.whileplaying = function() {
            var current  = new Date (this.position),
                minutes  = current.getMinutes(),
                seconds  = current.getSeconds();

            var current = minutes + ':' + seconds;

            $('.editable').html(current);
        }

        $('.bigPlay').click(function(e){
            if($(this).hasClass('playbtn')) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).removeClass('playbtn').addClass('pausebtn');
                preview.play({
                    onfinish: function() {
                        preview.stop();
                        $('.bigPlay').removeClass('pausebtn').addClass('playbtn');
                    }
                });


                return false;
            }

            if($(this).hasClass('pausebtn')) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $('.bigPlay').removeClass('pausebtn').addClass('playbtn');
                preview.stop();

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

The console shows:

```
-- SoundManager 2: HTML5 support tests (/^(probably|maybe)$/i): mp3: true (preferring flash), mp4: true (preferring flash), ogg: true, wav: true -- soundmanager2.js:1110
-- SoundManager 2 V2.97a.20120527 (AS2/Flash 8) + HTML5 audio, normal polling -- soundmanager2.js:1110
soundManager::createMovie(): Trying to load /bundles/bm/swf/soundmanager2_debug.swf soundmanager2.js:1110
soundManager::initMovie(): Waiting for ExternalInterface call from Flash... soundmanager2.js:1112
soundManager::externalInterfaceOK() (~0 ms) soundmanager2.js:1112
soundManager::init() soundmanager2.js:1112
soundManager: Attempting JS to Flash call... soundmanager2.js:1112
(Flash): SM2 SWF V2.97a.20120527 (AS2/Flash 8) soundmanager2.js:1112
(Flash): JS to/from Flash OK soundmanager2.js:1112
Flash security sandbox type: remote soundmanager2.js:1112
(Flash): Enabling polling, 50 ms interval soundmanager2.js:1112
-- SoundManager 2 loaded (OK) -- soundmanager2.js:1110
soundManager::initComplete(): calling soundManager.onload() soundmanager2.js:1110
soundManager.createSound(): previewer (/app_dev.php/track/play/4.mp3) soundmanager2.js:1110
SMSound() merged options: {
 id: previewer, 
 url: /app_dev.php/track/play/4.mp3, 
 type: audio/mp3, 
 autoLoad: false, 
 autoPlay: false, 
 loops: 1, 
 multiShot: true, 
 multiShotEvents: false, 
 pan: 0, 
 stream: true, 
 usePolicyFile: false, 
 volume: 100
} soundmanager2.js:1112
Loading sound previewer via HTML5 soundmanager2.js:1112
creating HTML5 Audio() element with URL: /app_dev.php/track/play/4.mp3 soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::adding event listeners: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
SMSound.load(): /app_dev.php/track/play/4.mp3 soundmanager2.js:1110
HTML5::load: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
0 soulshaka-club-69-underground-mix:529
soundManager.onload() complete soundmanager2.js:1110
HTML5::loadstart: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
SMSound.play(): "previewer" is loading - attempting to play.. soundmanager2.js:1110
SMSound.play(): "previewer" is starting to play soundmanager2.js:1112
setPosition(0): delaying, sound not ready soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::play: previewer, /app_dev.php/track/play/4.mp3 soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::waiting: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::loadedmetadata: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::loadeddata: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
SMSound._onload(): "previewer" loaded. soundmanager2.js:1110
HTML5::canplay: previewer, /app_dev.php/track/play/4.mp3 soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::playing: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::suspend: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::suspend: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::suspend: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::suspend: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::ended: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
SMSound._onfinish(): "previewer" soundmanager2.js:1112
SMSound.play(): "previewer" soundmanager2.js:1112
SMSound.play(): "previewer" is starting to play soundmanager2.js:1112
setPosition(0): setting position soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::play: previewer, /app_dev.php/track/play/4.mp3 soundmanager2.js:1112
HTML5::playing: previewer soundmanager2.js:1112
setPosition(0): setting position soundmanager2.js:1112
SMSound.play(): "previewer" soundmanager2.js:1112
SMSound.play(): "previewer" is starting to play soundmanager2.js:1112
setPosition(0): setting position soundmanager2.js:1112
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I have this issue as well. Hopefully someone can help soon.

Comment: maybe you have to `destruct` your soundObject before replay.
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smsound-destruct and also you use `soundManager.onload=` instead of `onready=`

Answer (score 2):

So I'm no expert in SoundManager2, but I was able to fix a bug that acted a lot like this. For me it was my server. There are HTTP headers you need to set when returning the audio data.

The technical notes section lists out some basic things you need to provide:
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/technotes/

Getting those headers right will get the audio playing. I needed to add a couple more headers just to get SoundManger2 to let me play the sound twice. Here are the headers from the response of my browser fetching and mpeg file. I may or may not need the "Accept-Ranges" header:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:close
Content-Length:30592
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
Server:Jetty(6.1.x)
```

Comment: Thanks!! I specifically set Content-Type/Content-Length/Accept-Ranges